# Access children value jquery

Tags: jquery

In below html I am clicking on id=2 then id=2, how can I access span tag Harr kane value in jQuery using sibling?

```
<div class="parentId">
   <span class="span1">
      <i class="i1">p</i>
      <span>Harr Kane</span>
   </span>
   <a class="a1" href="">
    <i id="2" class="i1">i1</i>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('span:first').text();
```

►`$(this)` - To select currently clicked element.

►`.parent()` - Will give the parent of the currently selected element.

►`.prev()` - will select the previous element.

►`.find()` - is used to find an element inside the selection.

►`:first` - is a pseudo selector used to select the first matching selection.

►`.text()` - to extract the text inside the selection

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#2").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert($(this).parent().prev().find('span:first').text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentId">
   <span class="span1">
      <i class="i1">p</i>
      <span>Harr Kane</span>
   </span>
   <a class="a1" href="">
    <i id="2" class="i1">i1</i>
   </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rino Raj how can I set current selected element text value ie <i id="2" class="i1">i1</i> in jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#2').click(function() {

  console.log($(this).closest('div.parentId').find('.span1').find('span').text()) 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentId">
  <span class="span1">
      <i class="i1">p</i>
      <span>Harr Kane</span>
  </span>
  <a class="a1" href="">
    <i id="2" class="i1">i1</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Using `.closest()` to get the the div.
Using `.find()` to target the correct element